# Create Trigger in MySql with Where Clause

Tags: mysql, sql, triggers

I have 2 tables, city and country. How do I create a trigger when a population from the city is decreased by more than 5% to decrease the population of every country on the same continent by 5%?

city:

```
|Name        | Country Code |Population
|------------|--------------|----------
| Dubai      | ARE          | 669181
| Abu Dhabi  | ARE          | 123456
| Sharja     | ARE          | 23456
```

country:

```
|Code  | Continent |Population| Name
|------|-----------|----------|----------
| ARE  | Asia      | 2441000  | United Arab Emirates
| ARM  | Asia      | 3520000  | Armenia
```

This is my query so far:

```
delimiter $$
    create trigger decreasePop 
    before update on city
    for each row
    begin 
        update city set population = population * 0.95;
    end $$
delimiter
```

but I can't figure out how to check for a percentage change without running into some errors.

How do I fix this? Thanks!

Comment: `create trigger` is not a SQL *query*. It's a SQL *statement*. Only `select` statements are *queries*.

Answer (score 0):

Use `IF` and the `new` and `old` pseudo rows.

```
...
IF new.population / old.population < 0.95 THEN
    UPDATE city
           SET population = population * 0.95;
END IF;
...
```